# App crashes after permissions are added?

Tags: android, sockets, permissions, android-manifest, crash

Ive been writing two Android applications, one a server and the other a client. The Apps couldn't connect to each other over my devices sockets, I would get access denied in the LogCat every time the Client tried to connect to the server, and when the server tried to create its own socket.

After research on the Matter I came to the conclusion that including the INTERNET permission in my android manifest file would allow the two Apps to connect to each other. However on adding this permission both my apps now crash on load. They were both running fine before (besides not connecting to one another) so I'm not sure whats happened. Ill post up the code and manifest file for both Apps and if you think its needed I can post up the LogCat as well.

Cheers in advance.

Code for server:

```
package com.example.simplerclienttest;

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Double lat=50.0, lng= 50.0, speed=(Math.random()*20), heading= 0.010011011, latB4, lngB4; 
    int time = 1;
    int trackId; 


    public void go(){

        try{
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(20000);

            while(true){

                Socket sock = serverSock.accept();

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                String header = getHeader();
                writer.write(header);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

            }

        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String getHeader(){
        latB4= lat;
        lngB4= lng;
        lat = lat + ((Math.random()-0.5)/100);
        lng = lng + ((Math.random()-0.5)/100);
        String Heading = "CBS";
        time = time + 1;
        trackId = 1;
        int depth = 0;
        speed = speed + ((Math.random()-0.5)*2);
        if((lat - latB4)>0 && (lng-lngB4)>0){
            heading = (((Math.atan(Math.abs(lng)/Math.abs(lat)))*180)/Math.PI);
        }else{
            if((lat - latB4)<0 && (lng-lngB4)>0){
                heading= (90 + (((Math.atan(Math.abs(lat)/Math.abs(lng)))*180)/Math.PI));
            }else{
                if((lat - latB4)<0 && (lng-lngB4)<0){
                    heading= (180 + (((Math.atan(Math.abs(lng)/Math.abs(lat)))*180)/Math.PI));  
                }else{
                    if((lat - latB4)>0 && (lng-lngB4)<0){
                        heading= (270 + (((Math.atan(Math.abs(lat)/Math.abs(lng)))*180)/Math.PI));
                    }else{
                        if((lat - latB4)==0 && (lng-lngB4)<0){
                            heading= 270.0;
                        }else{
                            if((lat - latB4)==0 && (lng-lngB4)>0){
                                heading = 90.0;
                            }else{
                                if((lat - latB4)>0 && (lng-lngB4)==0){
                                    heading= 0.0;
                                }else{
                                    if((lat - latB4)<0 && (lng-lngB4)==0){
                                        heading = 180.0;
                        }else{}}}}}}}}


        return(Heading+","+time+","+trackId+","+lat+","+lng+","+depth+","+speed+","+heading);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        go();


    }

    }
```

Manifest for server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.simplerclienttest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.simplerclienttest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Code for client:

```
package com.example.clienttest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ClientTestMain extends Activity {

final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_test_main);


    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            UpdateGUI();}},0,1000);
        }


final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                TextView Header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                TextView Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
                TextView TrackId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView Latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                TextView Longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                TextView Depth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                TextView Speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                TextView Bearing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

                try{
                    while(true){
                    Socket infoSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 20000);
                    InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(infoSocket.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
                    String message = reader.readLine();
                    String[] op = message.split(",");
                    Header.setText(op[0]);
                    Time.setText(op[1]);
                    TrackId.setText(op[2]);
                    Latitude.setText(op[3]);
                    Longitude.setText(op[4]);
                    Depth.setText(op[5]);
                    Speed.setText(op[6]);
                    Bearing.setText(op[7]);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    }
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }};



  private void UpdateGUI(){
      myHandler.post(myRunnable);
  }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.client_test_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Manifest for client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.clienttest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.clienttest.ClientTestMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

If seeing the LogCat would help please could you leave a message and ill add it :) thanks.

This is the LogCat for the crash of the client with the INTERNET permission:

```
09-05 14:12:59.500: D/AndroidRuntime(16366): Shutting down VM
09-05 14:12:59.500: W/dalvikvm(16366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bea1f8)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at com.example.clienttest.ClientTestMain$1.run(ClientTestMain.java:50)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-05 14:12:59.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16366):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the LogCat for client without the INTERNET permission:

```
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707): java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:573)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:559)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:127)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at com.example.clienttest.ClientTestMain$1.run(ClientTestMain.java:50)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 14:15:29.062: W/System.err(16707):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
09-05 14:15:29.070: W/System.err(16707):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: please add logs, its main part in your post

Comment: its not perrmission causes to crash but new block of code that entered because you added permission

Comment: "if you think its needed I can post up the LogCat as well." After a crash, Logcat is always helpful and the most important part besides the most relevant code

Comment: Also, your serversocket code should probably be done in a background `Thread` and it seems to me that you have an infinite `loop` which will cause problems most likely

Comment: hmm i thought i had something like an infinite loop going on but it loaded fine before the permission was added? yeah sorry ill add the LogCat its just that the device tell the LogCat everything so its hard to pinpoint the exact point of crash as there are at least 400 lines of information and more continuously streaming in but ill try my best :)

Comment: added the LogCats i hope that sheds some light on things :L

Comment: can you guys please get back to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of strict mode which is introduce in android 4.0.Accroding to this network work done on background thread not on main thread.To work on main thread define the strict mode permission in activity.